# Python: Is there any advantage to placing try code on the same line as the try statement?

Tags: python, coding-style, format, try-catch

I'm constantly seeing people write code like this:

```
try: some_function()
except: print 'something'
```

When I consider is significantly cleaner to do this:

```
try:
        some_function()
except:
        print 'something'
```

I'm trying to figure out why? Is there some inherent speed difference in placing code on the same line as the try? (Kind of like "in-lining", but not really).

Comment: the only advantage is saving 2 lines ...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put code blocks in. I was actually putting them in when you edited it :). Thanks!

Comment: given the world-wide shortage of line-breaks, be conservative.  (the answer is actually No, there is no difference, except readability.)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you really shouldn't be using tabs (or 8 spaces, if that's what you're doing) either. That doesn't make Guido cry like putting multi-clause statements on a single line, but it does make him get a little misty.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the former is a good practice.
People may think the try & except blocks are short enough to write in one line.

Quote from PEP8:

> While sometimes it's okay to put an if/for/while with a small body on the same line, never do this for multi-clause statements. Also avoid folding such long lines!
>
> Definitely not:
>
> ```
> try: something()
> finally: cleanup()
> ```

(Ref: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

So, always write try in a separate line is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in your question. Use the second form always: it is much more cleaner.
Also here is a good [Python style guide](http://code.google.com/p/soc/wiki/PythonStyleGuide) you might want to check out.

Comment: 'Use the second form always' - also, never use gotos and remember that globals() is evil, right?

Comment: @l4mpi: Considering that Python doesn't have gotos, that's not exactly hard. (OK, you can go look for the April Fool's goto module from a few years ago, which probably still works with CPython 2.7… but avoiding doing so is still easy.)

Comment: Sorry @abarnert, I forgot my `sarcasm` tags. It's just not good advice to tell someone "always use this one" - the shorter form has its advantages, and as long as the statement itself isn't complicated it isn't really hard to read (and remarkably simple compared to nested dict comprehensions and similar shenanigans).

Comment: I knew you were being sarcastic, but your sarcasm is misdirected. There's a reason Python doesn't have gotos. And there's also a reason PEP8 says "definitely not" to one-line multi-clause statements. It's not so much about being easier to read, as about being consistent across all Pythonic code, so you can understand the flow control before you've even read it. And 'remember that globals() is evil' is also universal advice: You may need to use it one day; remember that it's evil and be extra careful around it, and you'll be OK. Your statement is literally true, so the sarcasm is misplaced.

Comment: The goto comment was just for lampshading the attitude. About PEP8: I think this should be treated like the bible... as in, not taken literally. It also says to limit all lines to 79 characters, which is OK if you still work on SunOS5.6, but just unneccessary most of the time (and impossible in jython, think imports of classes with 100-char-long paths). For the specific case, the readability of a try with multiple simple excepts can sometimes be extremely improved by using the one-line form for the except statements and aligning the right sides. In the end it's mostly a matter of preference...

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with Joran, this is a matter of stylistic and readability preferences. Sure, the actual file size will be slightly larger with the encoded carriage return, but performance will not be impacted.